# Intrinsic Concentration of a extrinsic semiconductor.

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why the intrinsic Concentration of a semiconductor remains constant even while doping?

Comment: Your question looks unclear. Make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Generation and Recombination process..the overall intrinsic concentration of a semiconductor remains constant. This might also help you- https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-n-+-p-stay-constant-when-an-intrinsic-semiconductor-is-doped